# Bad input conditions for [number,number] form of input in C

Tags: c, input, conditional-statements, scanf

I have a function that should read input in form [number,number] or [number, number] and I need to do conditions for bad input. The input should end with EOF This is what i got now as a while cycle for input with conditions. The problem is, that it writes the bad input, for example for [1,2] [3,4] ]5,4 , but not for [1,2] [3,4] [5 . When the third coordinate is "unfinished" it won't write the bad input, it will work for the first 2 coordinates. Also there should be condition to write bad input, when less then 2 coordinates are input.

```
int a,b;
char par1, comma, par2;
printf("Your input here:\n");
while(scanf("%c %lf %c %lf %c", &par1, &a, &comma, &b, &par2)!=EOF)
   {
    if((par1!='[') || (comma!=',') || (par2!=']')) {printf("Bad input.\n");
    */ here I insert a and b in arrays */ 
    i++;
   }
if(!feof(stdin)) {free(arrayX); free(arrayY); printf("Bad input.\n);}
if(i<2) {printf("Bad input\n");}
```

I would be very thankful for any help. I am quite new in programming, so forgive me for stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would use regular expressions.

I'd recommend having a look at [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/)

For using `scanf`try doing it like this:

```
while((num_read = scanf("%c %lf %c %lf %c", &par1, &a, &comma, &b, &par2)) != EOF)
{
   if((par1!='[') || (comma!=',') || (par2!=']' || num_read != 5))
   {
        printf("Bad input.\n");
        ....
```

Also, there is some mistake with either: the indentation, or the `{` that opens after the `if`.

Comment: Thank you, but don´t you know if it is possible to do it somehow without the regular expressions? Because the programm is homework for school, so I probably can´t use the RE.

Comment: What if user input `[1,2] [3,4] [5,6k` ?